# How to choose the independent variables in a GLMM without performing stepwise selection? With a global model? How to decide then?

Tags: model-selection, model, glmm, stepwise-regression

I am trying to conduct an inferential binomial GLMM with a large dataset and many independent variables. I was attempting to do a stepwise AIC selection but keep reading it is a bad idea. However, even if I wanted to there are a lot of NAs and no complete cases which means I can't do it anyway. I heard the best way is through making a global model. Is this a good way to do it? How do you choose which variables are important to describe and present? I don't want to describe 20 different variables especially those with very small effect sizes. What is the best way to do this if stepwise selection and p-values are looked down on.

Comment: A sample of data and your key objectives  is a must to look for a solution.

Comment: a sample of results shall add to a faster solution.